# How to do an If Else in google sheets?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, compare

Right now I'm trying to figure out whether a cell contains one of two values, it will then perform an operation which depends on whatever value is in said cell. This is the function I have so far:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("btc", I2)), (E2*(1+10%)-D2),""), IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pp",I2)),E2-D2,""))
```

However I found that you cannot do 2 if statements in the same cell.

Comment: Put your second in the false of the first instead of the ""

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you are saying

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put your second in the false of the first instead of the `""`.  It is called nesting:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("btc", I2)), (E2*(1+10%)-D2),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pp",I2)),E2-D2,""))
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternate with nested IFERROR functions.

```
=IFERROR(E2*IFERROR(SIGN(SEARCH("btc",I2))*110%,SIGN(SEARCH("pp",I2)))-D2,"")
```

Comment: this is a more general approach, since takes in account any possible error case.